# Infinite Sets (1st yr Uni) and Axioms

Tags: hypothesis-testing, cantor-set, first-countable

This is my first question, so please be easy on me if it's too "conversational".

I've been asked to consider how the axioms of ZFC Set Theory, and any that underlie it, could influence the way in which mathematicians approach the subject of infinite sets. This is for a discussion (there is no "answer"), but I think I've found a fundamental issue with a proof that underpins modern mathematics.

I don't want to look like a fool at University, but I can't get the idea out of my head (surely I must be wrong... it has been a century since it was settled).

My question is:

What is the best way to verify a hypothesis if you lack a full understanding of the subject area?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand where the fundamental issue comes in. People who come up with (and verify) hypotheses in set theory *do* have a thorough understanding of the subject area.

Comment: Furthermore, surely the best way to verify a hypothesis without fully understanding it is by learning more about it so you do understand it, no?

Comment: Thanks Jam, what if further study causes someone to become blind to something "obvious"? That might sound ridiculous, but I honestly believe I have a way to show that the first and second proof by Cantor are incorrect (in the exact same way). I'm no expert, but the basic nature of my hypothesis must surely be provable/disprovable without me spending anothe x years studying it?

Comment: I think I see what you're asking. Whether advanced study makes people blind to certain things is an interesting question. But to be honest, the entirety of academia is built on the assumption that people don't get any less intelligent by studying. And I think that's quite a rational assumption: there are lots of people asking very critical questions about all hypotheses and it's rare that a layman (dis)proves an established result, so it should seem unlikely that all of mathematics is built on faulty reasoning.

Comment: And regarding whether your hypothesis disproves Cantor's proofs, it's exceedingly unlikely (no offense). Plenty of people think they've come up with proofs that Cantor was wrong all the time, but they're often wrong. One example I've seen was that taking any infinite set of integers, then taking the $n$th digit of each $n$th integer and finally changing all the digits and concatenating them to form a new integer, this new integer can't be in the original set (hence $\mathbb{N}$ is uncountable?). But this proof actually has faulty reasoning (though it's interesting to see why).

Comment: I'd invite you to share your hypothesis with the community here on stackexchange and we can see whether we can pick it apart. Or alternatively, you could ask one of your tutors at your university. But in any case, if you want to have your hypothesis tested, you should probably ask someone whether it's valid. But if you can't share your result, that's a shame but we really can't help you if we can't see it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be honest, the only options are (1) to *acquire* a full understanding of the subject area, or (2) to *ask* someone who already has it. A major issue here is that mathematics isn't an experimental science, and math having to do with infinity is especially not - so you can't just "test" the hypothesis in your basement.

Judging from the comments, you're concerned that an expert might be too "close" to the topic and become unable to see the problem; that's not something to worry about here. First of all, theorems like Cantor's Diagonalization were *not* always accepted - when first introduced, Cantor's theorems were heavily examined by experts who were predisposed to believe they were false. Second of all, math has the virtue that a proof is either correct or not - there's no opinion to be had there. Possibly you've noticed a problem that an expert wouldn't have seen, but if you point it out to them an expert *will* be able to tell whether it's really a problem. And if it isn't, they'll be able to explain to you what you're misunderstanding.

The natural next question is: where do you *find* such an expert? One option might be to go to your professor, but you've expressed a fear of "looking like a fool" - so I'd recommend someone you don't know, so that you don't care what they think of you. A ready source of such experts is right here, on StackExchange! You could just post your proposed flaw in the proof as a question, and you'll probably get a response very quickly.

One last note: I would consider it honestly very unlikely that what you've found is actually a flaw in the proof. The result that there are different sizes of infinity was a deeply surprising one, and as a result Cantor's theorems are among the most thoroughly cross-examined theorems in mathematics. However, I would encourage you to talk to someone about your idea - even if you aren't correct in thinking that the proofs fail, it would be useful for you as a scholar to find out *why* they don't.

Comment: Thank you Reese, your response was very thorough and helpful. I am working on the question... it might take a while to get the wording right.